# Next build fails because of webpack gl errors

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, next.js, deck.gl

I'm trying to build the NextJS App using `mapbox.gl` and `deck.gl`, it runs fine on my local server, however when I try to publish the application a  `webpack` error occurs:

> Failed to compile.
>   ./node_modules/@luma.gl/webgl/dist/es5/webgl-utils/webgl-types.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve 'gl' in '/Users/kingusha/Desktop/HTMLCSSJS/ReactApps/something/node_modules/@luma.gl/webgl/dist/es5/webgl-utils'

I've tried installing the `gl` module using `npm` and researching the matter but didn't find any solutions. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: did my answer make sense?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to answer back. I have tried what you have suggested, but It didn't solve the issue. I've just deployed the app with plain React instead of next, so It must have been server-side rendering and next compiling that was causing it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential issues that come to mind that could be causing this issue:

1. `mapbox-gl` wasn't properly installed and needs to be reinstalled:

   `npm i -S mapbox-gl`

**Note**: I don't think this is your issue since you can run it locally, but for completeness I will show this step.

2. `webpack` is unable to *properly resolve the `mapbox-gl` dependency* from its default resolution settings. Therefore, the resolution path for `mapbox-gl` needs to be set up manually.

Perhaps you could try manually specifying the `mapbox-gl` resolution path and seeing if this helps resolve your issue, something along the lines of:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
      "modules": ['node_modules', 'js'],
      "alias": {
          'mapbox-gl': path.resolve('./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js')
       }
  }
};
```

This will allow `webpack` to properly add the `mapbox-gl` dependency to the `JavaScript` bundle created during `webpack` builds. For more information about `webpack` resolve take a look at the official [documentation.](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/)

Hopefully that helps!